# Redux-Native Integration is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to integrate Redux with my React Native code, but for some reason, the output is not as expected.

I am expecting the payload (In this case 'Test') I am passing in Action.JS to be displayed dynamically on the Home screen...but instead i get a "(this.props.user)" displayed on my Home Screen..

Can someone please suggest.

This is what I am trying

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import NavigationContainer from './navigation/RootNavigator';
import reducers from './redux/reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
const store = createStore(reducers, middleware);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Action.js

```
export function login(){
    return function(dispatch){
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: 'test' });
    }
  }
```

Reducers.js

```
export default reducers = (state = {
    user: '',
  }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN': {
        return { ...state, user: action.payload }
      }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Home.Js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../styles'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {login} from '../redux/actions'

import { 
  Text, 
  View
} from 'react-native';

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(login())
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>(this.props.user)</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Where did you put your reducers? How did you connect it? Or maybe that's the one you're missing, I think this approach need a `combineReducers`.

Comment: change `(this.props.user)` to `{this.props.user}`

Answer (score 1):

For rendering, variables need to use `{}` as follows.

```
<Text>{this.props.user}</Text>
```

Comment: This worked... Thanks .. I highly appreciate it.. :)